# GiHub most watched repositories

Tags: github, github-api

I can get list of most watched repositories on GitHub using this URL

https://github.com/languages/Ruby/most_watched

But there are only 10 pages and 500 repositories. Can I get more watched repositories?

I tried to find the way to do this in GitHub API, but i didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Search part of the GitHub API - http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories

Do a search for all Ruby repositories (notice the language parameter) and extract the number of watcher for each repository. Since the repositories won't be sorted by the number of watchers, you would have to go through all the repositories and sort afterwards. This could take some time (depending on the number of repositories), but because you will probably not be doing this search often -- I think it's acceptable.